# Overreleasing an array in CFNetwork?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, instruments, cfnetwork

I've run into an issue with zombie/overreleased objects (in this case a CFArray). The problem is that I can't figure out where it's coming from. I'm doing a whole bunch of NSURLConnections at once, and according to Instruments, all the calls that lead to the overreleasing of the object are made in CFNetwork.

[image: instruments screenshot]

I'm kind of new to Instruments. Is there a way I can trace the call stack for these memory events? It might help me find where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If I remember correctly, instruments will tell you the exact *line* of code, so long as it isnt in a private framework... If only I could remember how...

Answer (score 0):

Enable NSZombie flag in edit scheme.It will let u know where exactly ur app is crashing.And make sure disable it once u figure out the crash.because it will not release all released objects wihch will lead to huge memory usage.

Comment: I do believe he has them enabled (instruments stops when it finds a zombie object).

Comment: Make sure whether its been enabled or not for sure..
Here is the path to disable it
Click on TopLeft Corner of ur xcode ,Right to stop button
EditScheme->Diagnostics->(uncheck)Enable Zombie objects.